# How to use jQuery autocomplete (=live search) with a Laravel Controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

This is (part of) my view, generated by [Laravel Forms](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html):

```
<form method="POST" action="http://laravelapp/search" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="g3RA...">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="terms">
</form>

<script>
$( function() {
    var testdata = [ "ActionScript", "AppleScript", "JavaScript" ];
    $( "#terms" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 1,
        source: '{{ URL::route('index.search') }}'
        //source: testdata
    });
});
</script>
```

These is the route for `index.search`:

```
Route::post('/search', 'IndexController@search')->name('index.search');
```

This is my `IndexController`:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
   return Response('Hello World');
}
```

For the sake of simplicity, I replaced the actual search algorithm with a static response `Hello World`. However, the autocomplete works fine if I uncomment the `//source: testdata` line in the javascript code. When I use the route to the IndexController, nothing happens.

When I press enter (=submit the form), a new page is loaded with `Hello World`, but there's no dynamic search result.

As you can see, I inserted the CSRF token and the `search()`method returns a valid response. However, it is not triggered by the javascript. My questions, thus, are:

- What's wrong with my code?
- Should the route be GET or POST?
- Should there be a form around the input field? Usual jQuery demo examples don't have it, but it's probably needed for the CSRF protection.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The assumption with the endpoint would be that the response should be json containing an array.  I don't see the logic in your method to return json, let alone an array.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I modified my code so that I now have a result collection and I send it back with the ->toJson() method. Problem solved! Can I somehow mark your comment as a solution?

Comment: added an answer detailing the same stuff.  @BarretWallace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autocomplete expects its source to be an array of data.  By default the way to respond this back to the client is in the json format.  You should try changing your endpoint to not only return an array, but encode that array into the json format so autocomplete will know how to handle it.